# Binding the meta key (a.k.a. super key / Windows key) to left click

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, mouse

How can I bind the meta key (a.k.a. [super key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_key_(keyboard_button)) / Windows key) to a left click? Hitting the meta key should trigger a left click, and pressing down on it should allow me to drag and drop (just like it would do when holding down left click).

I tried using System Preferences -> Shortcuts and Gestures:

[image]

but I cannot set "meta" alone as being a shortcut.

I use Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4 and Kubuntu 14.04 LTS x64.

(On Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate I can achieve that using the program [SmartNav](http://www.naturalpoint.com/smartnav/support/downloads.html).)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xdotool` + `xbindkeys`

1. insall `xdotool` and `xbindkeys`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool xbindkeys
   ```
2. generate the default configuration file for `xbindkeys`

   ```
   xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```
3. open `~/.xbindkeysrc` with some text editor

   ```
   kate ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```
4. add these lines in the end of the file

   ```
   "xdotool mousedown 1"
       Super_L
   "xdotool mouseup 1"
       Super_L + Release
   ```

   this will make the left 'windows/super/meta' button act like the left mouse button .
   for me the releasing thing didn't work specifically with the super button , but it worked with other buttons (I actually used `KP_Delete` which is the `del`/`.` button in the numpad, instead of using `Super_L` ), but I think this may be a hardware related issue.
5. save the file and close the editor.
6. start (or restart) xbindkeys

   ```
   sudo killall xbindkeys && xbindkeys
   ```